# Eclipse Indigo: how do I uninstall a plugin if the Help -> About Eclipse SDK dialog won't display?

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin

Scala-IDE is messing up my Help -> About Eclipse SDK dialog, so the obvious method of uninstalling is not working. (as mentioned [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583544/eclipse-3-7-indigo-about-dialog-error))

How can I uninstall it?

Comment: Hey @Jason, was this resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember for sure. I think so, but I seem to remember just reinstalling Eclipse.

Comment: Oh well.  I *hope* I helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Eclipse Marketplace > Installed > Uninstall' sometimes works as well.

Also, from [How do I remove a plug-in?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F)

> To physically remove the feature and its plug-ins, you will have to
>   manually remove the feature from the eclipse/features directory and its
>   plug-ins from the eclipse/plugins directory.

Answer (score 18):

On Eclipse Indigo ...

1. Click on Help > About Eclipse
2. Click on the "Installation Details" button
3. Select all the installed software you want to uninstall
4. Click "Uninstall ..."

Not sure why they have "hidden" this in the "About Eclipse" section.

Comment: Please read my question fully. I cannot access the About Eclipse dialog, therefore I cannot follow the usual method.

Comment: I tried this, but my "Uninstall" button (in Indigo) is disabled for anything installed. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 6):

Help -> Install New Software ....

In the "Available Software" dialog that opens, there is a tiny link towards the bottom labelled "already installed". Click on that, and it's another route to getting to the uninstall bit.

Not exactly intuitive, but it got me around this problem